# Azure Application Insights - trackEvent with custom properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights

We are using the client-side javascript SDK (via the [snippet-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#snippet-based-setup) integration) for Application Insights to [track custom events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent)

```
appInsights.trackEvent({name:"WinGame"});
```

How can I add custom properties to this? Something like this?!

```
appInsights.trackEvent({name:"WinGame", customProperties:{gameName:"Game 1", player:"my player 1"}});
```

Comment: No, the property is `properties` not `customProperties`. This is all in the [documentation if you read it](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#sending-telemetry-to-the-azure-portal)

Comment: you dont mean "if you read it" but "if you find it"...thanks anyway

Comment: @Liam...Why it is different here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#properties?

Comment: I don't know @GauravMantri , ask MS, their docs are always sketchy, especially around Azure. They seem to struggle to keep up with their own changes and documentation is often an after thought. A lot of the Azure function docs are still showing v1 screens despite the function SDK now being totally different since that incarnation. It's open source so you can always open a PR if you feel that strongly about it

Comment: anyway, if you want to create an answer here for people to easily find it, I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: I've submitted [an issue on that document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/72008)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen on the [JS Azure appinsights github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#sending-telemetry-to-the-azure-portal):

> Custom properties can be included in your telemetry through the
> properties named argument. This can be done with any of the Track
> APIs.
>
> ```js
> appInsights.trackEvent({   
>     name: 'some event',  
>     properties: { // accepts any type
>        prop1: 'string',
>        prop2: 123.45,
>        prop3: { nested: 'objects are okay too' }   
>     } 
> });
> ```